# Is the synapse launcher available for Ubuntu 16.04 and been tested too?

Tags: 16.04, synapse

I am about to upgrade to 16.04 from 15.10, but I'd like to know if the synapse app launcher is available for 16.04 and if it works just fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### It works!

I've been using 16.04 with **Synapse** for a while and I love it. It works flawlessly for me.

`sudo apt-get install synapse`

---

**[Note:** if you are using Ubuntu MATE, there have been [some](https://askubuntu.com/questions/780355/synapse-doesnt-work-on-16-04) [issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764427/ubuntu-mate-16-04-synapse-suddenly-crashes-while-typing) **]**