# Synapse doesn't work on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, synapse

Synapse, installed from the official repo, crashes after typing anything:

```
khajvah@khajvah-work:~$ synapse
[INFO 17:09:14.234703] [synapse-main:266] Starting up...
[INFO 17:09:14.304390] [synapse-main:208] Binding activation to <Control>space
[INFO 17:09:14.357984] [view-base:251] Screen is composited.
[INFO 17:09:14.359002] [controller:57] Using xim input method.
[WARN 17:09:14.417119] [desktop-file-service:343] Desktop session type is not recognized, assuming GNOME.
[WARN 17:09:14.473902] [ssh-plugin:114] /home/khajvah/.ssh/config: Error opening file: No such file or directory
[INFO 17:09:14.482539] [hybrid-search-plugin:179] keeps in cache now 366 file names
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

**Workaround**

The version from `ppa:synapse-core/testing` works fine.

Comment: See if ibus is a problem too.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like there is a bug as many people having the issue including myself on Ubuntu MATE. Please run  `$ GTK_IM_MODULE='' synapse` into your terminal and that should resolve it for you.

## Update

I you could also downgrade to older version that doesn't have have the bug. There I have found an answer by @OccamRazor in [in here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/773179/synapse-launcher-crashes-after-any-input-from-keyboard) which works very well when I tested.